# Vuetify: what does v-container inside router-view do?

Tags: layout, vue.js, vue-router, vuetify.js

In Vuetify's [pre-defined layouts](https://vuetifyjs.com/layout/pre-defined), there are two very similar pieces of example code:

```html
<v-app>
  <v-navigation-drawer app></v-navigation-drawer>
  <v-toolbar app></v-toolbar>
  <v-content>
    <v-container fluid>
      <router-view></router-view>
    </v-container>
  </v-content>
  <v-footer app></v-footer>
</v-app>
```

and

```html
<v-app>
  <v-navigation-drawer app></v-navigation-drawer>
  <v-toolbar app></v-toolbar>
  <v-content>
    <router-view>
      <v-container fluid></v-container>
    </router-view>
  </v-content>
  <v-footer app></v-footer>
</v-app>
```

The second one looks better in my app, but **it really confuses me how it works**. How can there be a `<v-container>` inside `<router-view>` when `<router-view>` is replaced by route content? What is this supposed to achieve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any direct content of `<router-view>` will be displayed when there is no matching route for that `<router-view>`. It will be replaced by the matched route component. It's placeholder content until a route is matched.